# Word-compatible (DOCX) software able to open references

Tags: text-editor, microsoft-word, word-processor

I'm trying to find an alternative to Microsoft Word software, able to open and save directly docx files. I already know that the common choice is OpenOffice/LibreOffice writer, but I'm not very satisfied with those . **My main interest is the bibliography references admin** included in Word 2007/2010/2013, I would like to open and edit references included in my docx files and save with no problem.

Some text-editors claims to be 100% compatible with Word docx files and they don't support that feature.

It doesn't matter if is open sourced software, preferably for Windows or Linux, plus for Android.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Could you please [edit] your post and fill some gaps: price-tag (must be free, or is there a budget), OS it should run on, features needed? See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for a guide of what is expected. Thanks!

Comment: Please explain why you don't want to use Microsoft Word.

Comment: Performance problems on my pc running most recent versions of Word.

Comment: I see different possible solutions: (a) You could maybe upgrade your hardware, with more active memory (RAM) and a SSD or if budget matters a SSHD (hybrid drive).  (b) You could purchase an older version of Office, maybe the 2010 or even the 2007. (c) Depending on the nature of the documents that you're editing, for future needs, you could possibly use a text processor using a totally different approach than Microsoft Office Word / LibreOffice Writer : LyX, which helps making TeX/LaTeX documents. However, this would not be for editing existing docx.